# Help on Ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I stumbled upon this ODE while preparing for an exam.$$5y=x^2+xy'-(y')^2$$ It was left as an exercise without any tips. I know I'm rude for asking for help without showing any effort but the problem itself lies in that I don't know which type of ODE this equation is. I'm pretty sure it's Lagrange's or Clairunt's equation because of the term $xy'$ but I can't really get it in the form $y=xf(y')+g(y')$. Any hints and tips are welcome!

Comment: Hint: Notice $x^2 + xy' - y'^2 = \frac54 x^2 - \left(y' - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2$. Change variable to $u = y - \frac{x^2}{4}$, the equation becomes $5u = u'^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

After differentiation making $y'(x) = p(x)$ we have

$$
2p(x)p'(x)-xp'(x)+4p(x)-2x=0
$$

and $p(x)  = a x + b$ is a possible $\mathcal{ansatz}$ for a general solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize you can differentiate equation right away. After rearranging it this way I got $p'(x)=-2$ if $x-2p\not=0$. If $x=2p$ we get singular solution $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$, and from $p'(x)=-2$ after integrating twice we get $y=-x^2+cx+d$. After substituting this solution in original equation we obtain $d=-\frac{c^2}{5}$. I'm satisfied with this although I'm still wondering why is this substitution necessary to obtain $d$?

Comment: You could also insert $p=c-2x$ into the original equation without introducing $d$.